# connect filebeat to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am trying to setup filebeat to logstash and get below errors at filebeat and logstash end:

filebeat; Version: 7.7.0
logstash  "number" : "7.8.0"

1. Modified /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml:

   enabled: true
   paths:
   commented output.elasticsearch
   uncommented output.logstash and added hosts: ["hostname:5044"]
2. Modified /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats_elasticsearch.conf:

   input {
   beats {
   port => 5044
   }
   }

   #filter {
   #}

   output {
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["hostname:9200"]
   }
   }

I started filebeat and got below error:

```
2020-07-06T08:51:23.912-0700    ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:106  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://hostname:5044)): Get http://hostname:5044: dial tcp ip_address:5044: connect: connection refused
```

Started logstash and its log below:

```
[INFO ] 2020-07-06 09:00:20.562 [[main]<beats] Server - Starting server on port: 5044
[INFO ] 2020-07-06 09:00:20.835 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[INFO ] 2020-07-06 09:00:45.266 [defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1] BeatsHandler - [local: x.x.x.x:5044, remote: y.y.y.y:53628] Handling exception: org.logstash.beats.InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid version of beats protocol: 71
[WARN ] 2020-07-06 09:00:45.267 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.logstash.beats.InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid version of beats protocol: 71
```

Please explain what else I should do.

Started filebeat and logstash as:

```
sudo /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -e -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats_elasticsearch.conf
```

Thanks

Comment: the filbeat, logstash and elastic instances are in diferent servers?

Comment: This got fixed. It was version mismatch and all the services are running on different nodes

Answer (score 1):

The version on the filebeat and logstash was different. Upgraded the filebeat version and fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was first to use same version for both and second under filebeat.yml, i should configure the below:

output.logstash:
hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]

instead of:

output.logstash:
hosts: ["http://localhost:5044"]